# Ассемблер. Поиск длины минимального слова

Tags: c++, алгоритм, ассемблер

Найти длину минимального слова в строке, строка состоит из слов разделенных пробелом.
Я пробовал делать через `repne scasb` но не получилось, так как не знаю, как узнать позицию пробела в строке

Comment: Код пробела - 32. Или просто `' '`. Записываете его в `AL`, с помощью `repne scasb` сравниваете каждый байт строки с `AL`.

Comment: Это понятно, а как получить позицию прлбела в строке, repne scasb определяет только вхождение пробела

Comment: Адрес пробела остается в `di` (или `edi`, если 32-битный код).

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать